# When I have the python-docx package installed it does not allow my program to run. As soon as I uninstall it my program runs

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-docx

Sorry for my lack of programming language but here is my problem:

I am creating a program that saves docx from text entrys. I can make it work with .doc files but it loses the nice formatting and newer file extension python-docx allows for. 
After installing python-docx and running my program from windows 10, the program instantly closes instead of running.
Here is the portion of the program where I am using the python-docx:

```
from docx import Document

titleentry = Entry(window1, width=60, bg="white").grid(row=2, 
    column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
obentry = Entry(window1, width=60, bg="white").grid(row=4, 
    column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=W, pady=4,)
lessentry = Entry(window1, width=60, bg="white").grid(row=6, 
    column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
input = titleentry.get()
inputObjective = obentry.get()
inputLesson = lessentry.get()
document = Document()
document.add_heading(input, 0)
document.add_heading(inputObjective, level=1)
document.add_paragraph(inputLesson)
document.save(input + '.docx')
```

As soon as I uninstall the package it runs as needed. I believe this is also the reason pyinstaller has issues with converting the py-to-exe.

Comment: Use `from docx import Document`. Avoid the `... import *` syntax for reasons you can find on search. Then reduce the program (or create another) that uses only `document` and literals, like `document=Document(); document.add_paragraph("foobar"); document.save("test.docx")` and modify your question providing that as the example. This example has too many factors to consider, most of which we have no way of knowing about, like what is `titleentry` and what does it do that could cause a problem.

Comment: I used literals and chanaged the import... it still has the same issue. It is odd because I tried to comment out all the docx related code lines but it did not work either. The only way to get it back to normal was uninstalling the package. I modified the question, thank you for the help thus far thought!

Comment: Your question still contains unknown items like `Entry`. No one knows what those do. When I say "a literal" I mean a string literal like "abcdef" or an int literal like 42. The three lines I spelled out for you above should trigger the problem. If not, it's not a problem with python-docx. This article might be helpful in understanding why that's required before someone can help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve